# body background color won't change

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure why, but the background color of the body won't change to the color I want. I can make the container div change. However, this creates the white border, which is awkward.

Here is my link: http://weddingtesters.net76.net/index.html

```
body {background-color: #dde5ec;}

#main {
width: 100%;
height:auto; 
overflow:auto;
position:relative; 
margin:0px;
background-color:#dde5ec;}

#main div {
float:left; }
#picture { 
width: 777px; 
height:334px; 
position: relative; 
margin-bottom:0px; 
margin-left: 200px; 
background: url(http://weddingtesters.net76.net/pictures/johnandlaura.png);
z-index: 10;
border-left:2px solid white;
border-right:2px solid white;}

#nav { 
width:200px; 
height: 400px; 
position:relative;  
margin-left:200px;
padding:0px;
margin-bottom:25px;
background-color:#C3FDB8;
border-left: 2px solid white;
border-bottom: 2px solid white;}

#text { 
width:577px; 
height: 400px;  
position: relative; 
margin-left:0px;
padding:0px;
margin-bottom:25px;
background-color:#C3FDB8;
border-right:2px solid white;
border-bottom: 2px solid white;}

h1 { 
border-right: 1px dashed black;
font: 25pt calibri; 
color: black; 
text-align: center;
margin:20px;} 

h2 {
font: 10pt candara;}

h3{ 
background: url(http://weddingtesters.net76.net/pictures/transparant.png);
width:100%; 
height:125px;
font: 20pt Palatino Linotype serif; 
color:black;
font-style : italic;}
```

Comment: it is changing. where is the problem? in which browser?

Comment: @user1510951: Remember to upvote useful answers, and mark as an answer the one that worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to start out, there's a few things you should consider adding to your project. The main one I'll point out is that you don't have a reset stylesheet, which is why you are probably seeing the "white border". Check out this reset stylesheet, for more information: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

So when I view this (PC/Chrome v20) the body doesn't work. But when I put in this reset stylesheet, it works :)

This reset stylesheet should also fix your "white border" problem, although I'm not 100% sure I know which bit you mean. As [Spiritfyre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/563460/spiritfyre) says, you have a border style on the `#picture` element, so I would presume this is intentional..?

Let me know if this doesn't explain it in more detail and I will try to help out further.

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
    background-color: #dde5ec;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Note the second line of the `body` style definition. This removes the white border around your `#main` div. Also, your style should be fine, I can't see why it shouldn't work.

Also, as for the 2px white border around your `#picture` div, that's because there's actually a `2px solid white` border.

**EDIT**

Your CSS sheet (http://weddingtesters.net76.net/mainstylesheet.css) is incorrectly written. It should be written as below:

```
body {
    background-color:#dde5ec;
}

#main {
    width: 100%;
    height:auto; 
    overflow:auto;
    position:relative; 
    margin:0px;
    background-color:#dde5ec;
}

#main div {
    float:left; 
}

#picture { 
    width: 777px; 
    height:334px; 
    position: relative; 
    margin-bottom:0px; 
    margin-left: 200px; 
    background: url(http://weddingtesters.net76.net/pictures/johnandlaura.png);
    z-index: 10;
    border-left:2px solid white;
    border-right:2px solid white;
}

#nav { 
    width:200px; 
    height: 400px; 
    position:relative;  
    margin-left:200px;
    padding:0px;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    background-color:#C3FDB8;
    border-left: 2px solid white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

#text { 
    width:577px; 
    height: 400px;  
    position: relative; 
    margin-left:0px;
    padding:0px;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    background-color:#C3FDB8;
    border-right:2px solid white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

h1 { 
    border-right: 1px dashed black;
    font: 25pt calibri; 
    color: black; 
    text-align: center;
    margin:20px;
} 

h2 {
 font: 10pt candara;    
}

h3{ 
    background: url(http://weddingtesters.net76.net/pictures/transparant.png);
    width:100%; 
    height:125px;
    font: 20pt Palatino Linotype serif; 
    color:black;
    font-style : italic;
}
```

This is how a CSS sheet should be correctly styled.

Comment: There's no real "correct" and "incorrect" way to write a stylesheet. Each to their own :)

Comment: True, but a CSS sheet should *not* contain HTML tags. Have a look at the original, I've shared the link to it in the post. :)

Comment: Ahh - you're right :D I thought you were just indenting/moving the opening/closing {}'s. My bad.

Yes, user1510951, you should *NOT* put HTML tags in a stylesheet! That's for CSS only :)

Comment: No, I'm just a stickler for tidy code (: And agree, CSS and CSS only :D But @user1510951, this should fix your problem. (:

Comment: Thanks for the help, y'all! I appreciate it (: I'm still not sure why the body background didn't work, but removing the white border seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i have check to your site and now you create a syte-sheet as like this

your css link is this is not correct coding 
http://weddingtesters.net76.net/mainstylesheet.css

```
<html>

<body> 

<style type="text/css"> 
BODY {background-color:#dde5ec;
margin:0px auto;}
#main {
    width: 100%;
    height:auto; 
    overflow:auto;
    position:relative; 
margin:0px;
background-color:#dde5ec;

}
#main div {
float:left; 
}
#picture { 
width: 777px; 
height:334px; 
position: relative; 
margin-bottom:0px; 
margin-left: 200px; 
background: url(http://weddingtesters.net76.net/pictures/johnandlaura.png);
z-index: 10;
border-left:2px solid white;
border-right:2px solid white;
}
#nav { 
    width:200px; 
    height: 400px; 
    position:relative;  
margin-left:200px;
    padding:0px;
margin-bottom:25px;
background-color:#C3FDB8;
border-left: 2px solid white;
border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
#text { 
    width:577px; 
    height: 400px;  
    position: relative; 
    margin-left:0px;
    padding:0px;
margin-bottom:25px;
background-color:#C3FDB8;
border-right:2px solid white;
border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
h1 { 
border-right: 1px dashed black;
    font: 25pt calibri; 
    color: black; 
    text-align: center;
margin:20px;
} 
h2 {
 font: 10pt candara;

}
h3{ 
background: url(http://weddingtesters.net76.net/pictures/transparant.png);
width:100%; 
height:125px;
font: 20pt Palatino Linotype serif; 
color:black;
font-style : italic;
}

</style>

</body>
</html>
```

This **style-sheet** is not **correct**

please **replace to into this**

```
body {background-color:#dde5ec;
margin:0px auto;}
#main {
    width: 100%;
    height:auto; 
    overflow:auto;
    position:relative; 
margin:0px;
background-color:#dde5ec;

}
#main div {
float:left; 
}
#picture { 
width: 777px; 
height:334px; 
position: relative; 
margin-bottom:0px; 
margin-left: 200px; 
background: url(http://weddingtesters.net76.net/pictures/johnandlaura.png);
z-index: 10;
border-left:2px solid white;
border-right:2px solid white;
}
#nav { 
    width:200px; 
    height: 400px; 
    position:relative;  
margin-left:200px;
    padding:0px;
margin-bottom:25px;
background-color:#C3FDB8;
border-left: 2px solid white;
border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
#text { 
    width:577px; 
    height: 400px;  
    position: relative; 
    margin-left:0px;
    padding:0px;
margin-bottom:25px;
background-color:#C3FDB8;
border-right:2px solid white;
border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
h1 { 
border-right: 1px dashed black;
    font: 25pt calibri; 
    color: black; 
    text-align: center;
margin:20px;
} 
h2 {
 font: 10pt candara;

}
h3{ 
background: url(http://weddingtesters.net76.net/pictures/transparant.png);
width:100%; 
height:125px;
font: 20pt Palatino Linotype serif; 
color:black;
font-style : italic;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems in your CSS file listed below:

1. CSS file should not be wrapped around `<html>`, `<head>` or `<body>`
   tag or any other html tag.
2. Style(`<style>`) tag should only be used if CSS is internal(inside
   the html document.)
3. background-color property is given to `#main` div so, the body is not
   taking any background-color changes as `#main` is child of body & with
   width & height 100%.